# Error loading glyphs and tiles in offline map using Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, offline, openmaptiles

I am trying to load offline map using Mapbox framework used in OpenMapTiles iOS project. I am loading map using json file with additional sprite and glyph files to display labels on maps. Map is successfully loading in offline mode BUT there are no labels and images loaded which shows that the json file (i.e. bright.json) is loading but cannot find sprite and glyph paths mentioned in the json file. I've included the sprite and glyph folders in the project and they are referenced in the json file as follows:

```
"sprite": "asset://sprites/sprite",
"glyphs": "asset://glyphs/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"
```

On compiling, project is running and map is showing with following errors (multiple errors) in the console:

```
[ERROR] {}[Style]: Failed to load tile 14/8476/4729=>15 for source openmaptiles: Not found in MbTile database
[ERROR] {}[Style]: Failed to load glyph range 0-255 for font stack Klokantech Noto Sans Italic:
```

Please help me as to how to refer to the sprite and glyph folders in the project from json file. If more information is required, please comment so that I can edit the question.